# Individual User's Permission Using Enterprise Search

Tags: permissions, enterprise-search

Is it possible to use enterprise search to figure out an individual user's permission in a web app? I would like to get all the root sites along with the sub-sites across all the site collections...

Comment: The Membership web part should list off the sites they have access to. Have you checked that out?

Comment: That has some limitations such as the user has to have contributor rights on a site for that to show up on the membership webpart. If the user is a site collection administrator or has full control over the site, the webpart doesn't pick up the site.

Comment: Ok. You might be able to use the search results web part, and filter the results out, not sure if you can get just the sites however.